# SQL number greater than select results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling to think of a way to do this with T-SQL.

I have a table which is populated every 5 seconds with the prices of three currencies (GBP, EUR & USD)

I've created a trigger (after insert), which selects the last 5 records entered for a given currency:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Price from dbo.prices where coin='GBP' ORDER BY Date Desc
```

I want to determine if the last inserted currency price is greater than the selected 5 above, how do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Triggers do not select data.  Please show the trigger and explain what you are doing.  Also, explain what to do when multiple rows are inserted at the same time . . . do the previous 5 values include those being inserted?

Comment: As well as the trigger, it would be helpful to show an example using test data, as the description you have given isn't completely clear.  *(A picture is worth a thousand words, example data being the picture...)*

Comment: You can use the `LAG` or `LEAD` windowing functions to retrieve the next/previous value according to some order. You can use the `OVER` clause to return the MAX value in the last 5 rows. `if the last inserted currency price is greater than the selected 5 above` isn't that the *first* entry returned?

Comment: Are you asking how to compare the values in the `inserted` table against the values returned by the TOP 5 query?

Comment: @MatBailie "A picture is worth a thousand words"...Data posted as formatted text is worth more :P

Comment: @HoneyBadger - You're being too literal with my quote.  "Data as Formatted Text is worth a thousand words" doesn't have any cultural context.

Comment: @MatBailie, it was a joke, though with a serious connotation.

Comment: An trigger does not display data to my understanding.  The last insert would be the last 5.

Answer (score 1):

As I guess: there cant be two entries for the same currency at one time. Only one insert per currency per some time (5sec). So this should fit yours requirements:

```
declare @prices  table ([Date] int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, Price float, coin varchar(3));  
insert into @prices  (coin, Price) values 
('GBP', 3.20),('EUR', 3.14),('USD', 3.14),
('GBP', 3.17),('EUR', 3.16),('USD', 3.11),
('GBP', 3.14),('EUR', 3.13),('USD', 3.16),
('GBP', 3.15),('EUR', 3.12),('USD', 3.17),
('GBP', 3.16),('EUR', 3.17),('USD', 3.11),
('GBP', 3.15),('EUR', 3.14),('USD', 3.12),
('GBP', 3.19),('EUR', 3.14),('USD', 3.16)

select
    case
        when NEW.Price > PREV.Price Then 'yes'
        else 'No'
    end as CURR_JUMP_UP
from
    (
        select top 1 COALESCE(Price,0) Price, [Date]
        from @prices where coin='GBP' order by [Date] desc
    ) NEW
    cross apply
    (
        select MAX(Price) Price from
        (
            select top 5 Price
            from @prices
            where coin='GBP' and [Date]<NEW.[Date]
            order by [Date] desc
        ) t
    ) PREV
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
DECLARE @AmountLastFiveEntry DECIMAL= (SELECT TOP 5 SUM(Price) FROM dbo.prices WHERE 
    ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
    FROM dbo.prices where coin='GBP' ORDER BY Date Desc) where coin='GBP' ORDER BY Date Desc)
     IF  @AmountLastFiveEntry<(SELECT TOP 1 Price 
    FROM dbo.prices where coin='GBP' ORDER BY Date Desc)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @AmountLastFiveEntry --To do task
    END
```

Comment: Question is confusing but I don't think the sum of the prior 5 is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger part is confusing

This will report if the latest price is higher (or equal) to the largest of the prior 5.

```
declare @currency table (iden int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, exchange smallint,  coin tinyint);  
insert into @currency (coin, exchange) values 
       (1, 1)
     , (1, 2)
     , (1, 3)
     , (1, 4)
     , (1, 5)
     , (1, 6)
     , (2, 1)
     , (2, 2)
     , (2, 3)
     , (2, 4)
     , (2, 5)
     , (2, 3);

select cccc.coin, cccc.exchange 
     , case when cccc.rn = cccc.rne then 'yes'
            else 'no'
       end  as 'high'
from ( select ccc.iden, ccc.coin, ccc.exchange, ccc.rn 
            , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ccc.coin order by ccc.exchange desc, ccc.rn) rne 
       from ( select cc.iden, cc.coin, cc.exchange, cc.rn  
              from ( select c.iden, c.coin, c.exchange 
                          , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by coin order by iden desc) as rn
                     from @currency c
                   ) cc 
              where cc.rn <= 6 
            ) ccc
     ) cccc
where cccc.rn = 1
order by cccc.coin
```